# Android: Background thread in Singleton class

Tags: android, multithreading, background, handlers

I have Singleton class which holds all the data (visitors of some site) and the data is updated by a service. I have an interface, which is implemented by an (list) activity (which shows visitors), so now as I get the data updated, I simply call the interface method so that the list activity can refresh it.

Now I need to maintain the time visitors are on site (at client end). I want to make a thread in Singleton class which will run a loop after every second, but I am not able to call any method on Main thread, using Handlers.
Here's the code of thread:

```
void startHeavyDutyStuff() {
          Thread t = new Thread() {
              public void run() {
                  try {
                      while(true) {
                          sleep(1000);
                          ArrayList<VisitorMC> data =  SharedAppManager.appManager().visitorsData;

                          boolean doReload = false;
                          for (VisitorMC item: data) {
                              item.secsOnSite++;
                              if(item.secsOnSite == 60) {
                                  item.secsOnSite = 0;
                                  item.minsOnSite++;
                                  doReload = true;  
                              }
                          }
                          if(doReload) {
                              messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                          } else {
                              messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                          }
                      }
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
          };
          t.start();
      }
```

And here's the code where I am making the Handler on Main Thread (in Singleton class):

```
private SharedAppManager() {

            //Initialization of the data.

        Looper.prepare();
        messageHandler = new Handler() {
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  
                  switch(msg.what) {
                  case 0:
                      Log.d("THREAD", "after every second");
                      break;
                  case 1:
                      if(visitorsDelegate != null) {
                            visitorsDelegate.updateVisitorsTime();
                        }
                      break;
                  default:
                  }
              }
          };
        startHeavyDutyStuff();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
I need to update the UI after each second, that's why I am running a separate thread which could change the Data and call update on UI.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is: "I want to make a thread in Singleton class which will run a loop after every second". There is no need for this. Store the time the users arrive on the site. To determine how long they have been on the site, subtract their arrival time from the current time.

Comment: I need to update the UI after each second, I have found out the issue, I'll answer it asap.